# PYQT Qcombobox set value selected to a variable

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a combox, and want to add the vaue selected in the box to a variable.  The variable.  I tried a few things from the documentation and was only successful on setting it to a Qlabel.  Any help please

```
     self.languageLbl = QtGui.QLabel("Download_IVR", self)
     comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
     comboBox.addItem("IVR_ITALY")
     comboBox.addItem("IVR_FRANCE")
     comboBox.addItem("IVR_SPAIN")
     comboBox.addItem("IVR_GERMANY")
     comboBox.move(650, 250)
     comboBox.resize(150,40)
     self.languageLbl.move(650,150)
     comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.languageChoice)

 def download_button(self):

     ivrLang = self.comboBox.currentText()
```

I want to set ivrLang to the item selected in the combobox.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't connecting your signal to your callback function.  You need:

```
self.combobox.activated[str].connect(self.download_button)
```

And download button should look like:

```
def download_button(self, text):
    irvLang = text
```

Note that you still haven't done anything with that variable `irvLang`.

Also it would be wise to make the comboBox and attribute of your class using `self`:

```
self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
```

EDIT:
Here is a complete example that does what you *seem* to want.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.cb = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.cb.addItem("One")
        self.cb.addItem("Two")
        self.cb.activated[str].connect(self.selected)

    def selected(self, text):
        self.selected_text = text
        print(self.selected_text)

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
mw = MainWindow()
mw.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting ivrLang to a Qlabel.  So as the QLabel is displayed, the variable is set to the text of the QLabel.  That way I get the Label, and variable at the same time.  Perhaps maybe not the best way to do it, but it works

```
    def languageChoice(self, text):

        self.languageLbl.setText(text)
    def download_button(self, text):
        directoryUser = self.directory
        ivrNum = self.lblNumber.text()
        username = self.userName.text()

        ivrLang = self.languageLbl.text()
```