# PyQt5: How to use specific COMBO box option to display widget container?

Tags: python, python-3.x, combobox, pyqt5

Hi can anyone please tell me about it? I am new to PyQt.

For instance I have 3 options A, B and C in a combobox and if I select A, it should display one set widgets, maybe call X. If I choose B, it should display another set of widgets say Y and so on.

Further I have grouped all the widgets to be displayed in respective containers using GROUP box. Specifically, Here I just want to link **A** option of Combobox to the **groupbox**.

Thank You :)

This is my Code here:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):



    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 40, 281, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("-")
        self.comboBox.addItem("A")
        self.comboBox.addItem("B")
        self.comboBox.addItem("C")

        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 90, 631, 321))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")

        **#######################################################**   
        self.groupBox.hide()
        **#######################################################**

        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 40, 391, 101))
        self.pushButton_1.setObjectName("pushButton_1")

        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 220, 150, 61))
        self.label_1.setStyleSheet("font: 14pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")


        **#######################################################**
        cur_txt = self.comboBox.currentText()

        if  cur_txt == 'A':
            self.groupBox.show()
        else:
            self.groupBox.hide()
        **#######################################################**

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Yupp"))
        self.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Press Me1"))
        self.label_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Hello Moto1"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Press Me2"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Hello Moto2"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The majority of the part has been generated using Qt designer. Just the things between **#** has been written by me. I know there are somethings which are wrong but I don't know how to rectify them.

Comment: welcome to S.O.! Please show us what you have tried

Comment: @alfonso.kim
Thank you for the reply. I have added the code. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the following link:
[PYQT Qcombobox set value selected to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911596/pyqt-qcombobox-set-value-selected-to-a-variable?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

It is quite helpful.

Just had to add the following lines to the code. The code looks neat by creating a separate method (temp_var).

```
self.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.temp_var)

def temp_var(self, text):
    cur_txt = text
    if  cur_txt == 'A':
        self.groupBox.show()

    else:
        self.groupBox.hide()
```